# How to remove the space between \TeX\ and NICIANS to make it TEXNICIANS with fancy TEX

Tags: spacing, symbols

I want to remove the space between \TeX\ and NICIANS to make it TEXNICIANS with fancy TEX. But got error when no space between \TeX\ and NICIANS
Below is the code for the .tex file:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

Hello \TeX\ NICIANS!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just do ```Hello \TeX NICIANS!```

Comment: @LuisSibaja Thank you! If you like, you can put your answer below and I accept it as a correct answer.

Comment: Another way is `{\TeX}NICIANS`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just do

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

Hello \TeX NICIANS!
\end{document}
```

And it gives the desired output.